# Unable to create feature branch in git repository

Tags: java, git, maven

I am trying to create a feature branch in my application. But getting the following error while running "mvn jgitflow:feature-start"

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and maven version 3.3.9 and jdk 7

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jgitflow-plugin:1.0:feature-start (default-cli) on project my-application: Error starting feature: error configuring remote git repo with url: null: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

And the .git/jgitflow.log

```
init: ## _Command call():_ 
init:     _method start:_ getOrInitGit
init:         _ looking for git folder in /home/work/projects/my-application _
init:         _ found existing git folder _
:     _method END:_ 
GitHelper: _method start:_ remoteBranchExists
GitHelper:     _ checking for branch: master _
GitHelper:     _ got 29 remote refs _
GitHelper:     _ ref name: refs/remotes/origin/1.0.x _
GitHelper:     _ ref simple name: 1.0.x _
GitHelper:     _ simple name equals branch? false _
GitHelper:     _ ref name: refs/remotes/origin/1.1.x _
GitHelper:     _ ref simple name: 1.1.x _
GitHelper:     _ simple name equals branch? false _
GitHelper:     _ ref name: refs/remotes/origin/1.2.x _
GitHelper:     _ ref simple name: 1.2.x _
GitHelper:     _ simple name equals branch? false _
GitHelper:     _ ref name: refs/remotes/origin/master _
GitHelper:     _ ref simple name: master _
GitHelper:     _ simple name equals branch? true _
: _method END:_ 
GitHelper: _method start:_ remoteBranchExists
GitHelper:     _ checking for branch: develop _
GitHelper:     _ got 29 remote refs _
GitHelper:     _ ref name: refs/remotes/origin/1.0.x _
GitHelper:     _ ref simple name: 1.0.x _
GitHelper:     _ simple name equals branch? false _
GitHelper:     _ ref name: refs/remotes/origin/1.1.x _
GitHelper:     _ ref simple name: 1.1.x _
GitHelper:     _ simple name equals branch? true _
: _method END:_ 
# JGitFlow Log - Wed Oct 05 2016 12:25:34 IST

  ## Configuration
    JGit Version: 3.0.0.201306101825-r
    JGitFlow Version: 0.21
    Master name: master
    Origin master exists = true
    Develop name: develop
    Origin develop exists = true
    feature name: feature/
    release name: release/
    hotfix name: hotfix/
    support name: support/
    versiontag name: 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _ # Maven JGitFlow Plugin _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _ 

 _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _   ## Configuration _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _ 
 _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     Maven Version: 3.3.9 _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _ 
 _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     Maven JGitFlow Plugin Version: 1.0 _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _ 
 _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     args:  _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     base dir: /home/work/project/myapplication _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     default development version: null _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     default feature name: null _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     default release version: null _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     release branch version suffix: release _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     tag message: tagging release ${version} _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     allow snapshots: false _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     auto version submodules: false _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     enable feature versions: true _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     enable ssh agent: true _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     feature rebase: false _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     interactive: true _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     keep branch: false _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     no build: false _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     no deploy: false _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     no tag: false _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     pushFeatures: true _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     pushReleases: false _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     pushHotfixes: false _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     squash: false _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     update dependencies: true _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _     use release profile: true _
DefaultFlowFeatureManager: _ 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 _
DefaultProjectHelper: _ installing ssh console credentials provider _
DefaultProjectHelper: _ installing ssh-agent credentials provider _
```

Comment: that `url: null` looks suspicious.

Comment: Why the url is null? how should we configure git with remote url?

Comment: You are asking me why it is null? You tell me! Probably missconfiguration.

Comment: I am unable to figure out where i made a mistake on configuration but other basic git commands are working fine except this.. Any idea??

Comment: any inputs here really appreciated

Comment: If I am Switching remote URLs from SSH to HTTPS, I am able to create a feature branch without any issues.. What I missed while ssh key generation?

Comment: maybe... the key? :)